# Does Set which we get in driver.getWindowhandles() retain order

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a confusion whether the set which return windows handles in selenium retain order in which windows are opened, I mean like first window will be at first position, next window opened at next position and so on.

This is the code:

```
Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowhandles()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let us have a look at the call to `getWindowhandles()` method.

[image: getWindowhandles]

So its clear that `getWindowhandles()` method returns a `Set` of type `String` so we are pretty much correct when we mention:

```
Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowhandles();
```

Now, I would keep my Answer restricted to `Mozilla Firefox` as it follows a distinct Specification inline with `W3C Specs`.

The [**`WebDriver W3C Specification`**](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#get-window-handles) clearly mentions the following:

> **`The Get Window Handles command returns a list of window handles for every open top-level browsing context. The order in which the window handles are returned is arbitrary.`**

About the **window handle** the [**`WebDriver W3C Specification`**](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#dfn-window-handle) also clearly says :

> **`Each browsing context has an associated window handle which uniquely identifies it. This must be a String and must not be "current"`**.
>
> **`The web window identifier is the string constant "window-fcc6-11e5-b4f8-330a88ab9d7f"`**.

**Hence we can conclude that the order is not retained.**

### Solution:

In this case, if we need to shift Selenium's focus from first window to second window, then subsequently to the third window and traverse back, we can implement a logic to retain all the window handles in the `Set` and simply compare the `window handle` values before invoking `driver.switchTo().window(win_handle);` as follows:

```
String parent_window = driver.getWindowHandle();
System.out.println("Parent Window ID is : "+parent_window);
element2.click();   // WebElement which opens a new window
Set<String> allWindows = driver.getWindowHandles();
for(String child_1:allWindows)
    if(!parent_window.equalsIgnoreCase(child_1))
        driver.switchTo().window(child_1);
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
String child1_window = driver.getWindowHandle();
System.out.println("Child 1 Window ID is : "+child1_window);
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Link")).click();    //Link which opens a new window
Set<String> all_Windows = driver.getWindowHandles();
for(String child_2:all_Windows)
    if(!parent_window.equalsIgnoreCase(child_2) && !child1_window.equalsIgnoreCase(child_2))
        driver.switchTo().window(child_2);
String child2_window = driver.getWindowHandle();
System.out.println("Child 2 Window ID is : "+child2_window);
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the driver you are using. Some keep the order and some don't.
The [WebDriver protocol](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#get-window-handles) says that the order is arbitrary:

> The Get Window Handles command returns a list of window handles for
>   every open top-level browsing context. The order in which the window
>   handles are returned is arbitrary.

This is probably why all the handles are placed in a `Set` to prevent you form accessing an handle by index.

If you only have 2 windows then simply switch to the one which is not the current window :

```java
Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
handles.remove(driver.getWindowHandle());
driver.switchTo().window(handles.iterator().next());
```

But if you have more than 2 windows, then keep track of each new window or iterate over each window until you get the expected one:

```java
Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
handles.remove(driver.getWindowHandle());

for (String hwnd : handles) {
    driver.switchTo().window(hwnd);

    if (driver.getCurrentUrl().contains(...)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: although driver.getWindowHandles(); returns  set, but internal implementation is an ordered set.  I've checked the selenium web driver implementation in firefox , it is ordered by create time.

Comment: @abhishek Sharma, it depends on the driver. For instance the Internet Explorer driver doesn't return the handles sorted by the time the window was created. It's incorrect to state that the handles are sorted when it's not required by specification or intended by design. Moreover the code you observed from the Firefox driver could change at any time and behave differently without any warning.

Comment: @abhishekSharma Can you please point us to the implementation in Firefox, where it mentions to be ordered by create time?

Comment: @FlorentB. Actually this feature is at risk, as the public API says it returned a set, which means it could be changed to use unordered set implementation in future.

Answer (score 0):

`Set` is just an `interface`. In order to retain order, you have to use a specific implementation of that interface and the sub-interface `SortedSet`,